# F# List.iter doesn't print

Tags: list, function, oop, types, f#

I'm trying out OOP in F# and have run in to a problem. I'm trying to build a drone and an airspace class, but for some reason my printDrones function does not work so I have no way to check if the rest of it even works. I don't get any errors, but the function just doesn't print anything out. I think I might have some problems with my types or list functions but I've tried so many things now I'm about to give up. Hopefully someone here can help me out!

```
type Drone(startposition: (float * float), destination: (float * float), speed: float) =
    let mutable position = startposition
    let a = fst destination - fst position
    let b = snd destination - snd position
    let c = sqrt(a**2.0 + b**2.0)
    let speeddir = (a/c, b/c)
    member this.fly =
        position <- (fst position + (fst speeddir * speed), snd position + (snd speeddir * speed))
    member this.getPos = position
    member this.isFinished =
        (fst startposition - fst destination)*(fst position - fst destination) < 0.0


type Airspace() =
    let mutable drones: Drone List = []
    member this.droneDist (d1: Drone) (d2: Drone) : float =
        let d1pos = d1.getPos
        let d2pos = d2.getPos
        let a = fst d1pos - fst d2pos
        let b = snd d1pos - snd d2pos
        sqrt(a**2.0+ b**2.0)
    member this.flyDrones() =
        drones |> List.iter (fun x -> x.fly)
    member this.addDrone(dr: Drone) =
        drones <- dr :: drones
    member this.printDrones() =
        drones |> List.iter (fun x -> printfn "%A" (x.getPos))

let aspace = Airspace()

aspace.addDrone(Drone((50.0,100.0),(0.0,0.0), 20.0))
aspace.addDrone(Drone((0.0,100.0),(0.0,0.0), 20.0))
aspace.addDrone(Drone((25.0,100.0),(0.0,0.0), 20.0))
aspace.addDrone(Drone((75.0,100.0),(0.0,0.0), 20.0))
aspace.flyDrones
aspace.printDrones
```

Comment: `flyDrones` and `printDrones` have type `unit->unit` (they are functions), so you need to invoke them by passing the unit value to them: `aspace.printDrones()`

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid like that. Thanks a lot for the help!